# Reading/writing to/from a .CSV file from a web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I am trying to create a mini "comments board" at work.  There are 10 of us, and I want each of us to be able to add items to it, for everyone to be able to view.  The idea is to structure it as an HTML web page (for internal consumption only), with data being written to and read from a CSV file which would reside in the same folder on the server.  I would like to display it as a table on the web page, and enable individuals to add new entries which get written to the CSV file and displayed in the table.  I'm okay with basic HTML, but I don't know how to go about reading from and writing to a CSV file.  I've read bits about Javascript, PHP, SQL etc, but I'm not sure of the best approach.  Any guidance (including pointers to working examples of code) would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have SQL, why wouldn't you want to store it as a table?

Comment: I don't think I have SQL!  Just one of the many tools that I've read bits about.

Comment: If you want a very simple solution why don't just use a tried and tested solution, such as Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do that only with Javascript, you could use Node.Js server in order to retrieve and store data for all consummers. But, even if you create a PHP, Node.Js, Ruby, Python (...) script, you must develop an API in order to be able to retrieve data and store them in a single database (CSV, MySQL, MongoDB, etc.).

The realtime could be a great solution here, with something like [Pusher](http://You%20can%20also%20do%20that%20in%20real%20time%20with%20something%20like). All of that depend of what you're really want. There's some documentations about [RestAPI](https://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/), with or without [some PHP frameworks](http://www.gajotres.net/best-available-php-restful-micro-frameworks/)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm totally new to all this, so I don't actually understand any of the above!  I had hoped that there might be a very simple solution out there which would enable me to get data from a CSV file and display it in a table in HTML - perhaps just a few lines of javascript code that I could embed into the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the code below as a starting point for your mini-board.  Just pass the constructor a path that is writeable by your web server.

The following just takes a form, that will take a message that consists of a timestamp, a name and a comment.  After posting, this is saved to the CSV file.

All comments are stored in an array, and each time a comment is added, it is added to the array, and then the whole array is saved to disk, as a CSV.

There is no backing up of the board, and no file locking, it lacks finesse. 
Also there is no user login system or anything. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

It works as a pure html/php solution that you are free to customise.

```
<?php
class Board
{
    public $path_to_csv;
    public $comments = [];

    public function __construct($path_to_csv)
    {
        $this->path_to_csv = $path_to_csv;
        $this->load();
    }

    public function load()
    {
        if(!is_file($this->path_to_csv))
            file_put_contents($this->path_to_csv, '');
        if (($fh = fopen($this->path_to_csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($fh)) !== FALSE) {
                $this->comments[] = $data;
            }
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }

    public function addComment($ts, $username, $comment)
    {
        $this->comments[] = array($ts, $username, $comment);
        $this->save();
    }

    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $fp = fopen($this->path_to_csv, 'w');
        foreach($this->comments as $comment) {
            fputcsv($fp, $comment);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

class ViewHelpers
{
    public function form($action = '', $ts)
    {
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="<?=$action ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="ts" value="<?=$ts ?>">
            <label for="username">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br />
            <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit comment">
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    public function escape($string)
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($string);
    }
    public function table(array $comments)
    {
        if(!count($comments)) return; // No comments equals don't show.
        //$comments = array_reverse($comments);
        ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        User
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Comment
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach($comments as $comment) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?=date('r', $this->escape($comment[0])); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?=$this->escape($comment[1]); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?=nl2br($this->escape($comment[2])); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    public function feedback($string)
    {
        if(!$string) return;
        ?>
        <p>
            <?=$this->escape($string); ?>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}

// Path to where you want to store your csv file.
$board = new Board('/tmp/comments.csv');
$feedback = '';

// Process form submissions.
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $ts = isset($_POST['ts']) ? $_POST['ts'] : null;
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $comment  = isset($_POST['comment'])  ? $_POST['comment'] : null;
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($comment)) {
        $board->addComment($ts, $username, $comment);
    }
    else {
        $feedback = 'Please fill in all fields.';
    }
}
$viewHelpers = new ViewHelpers;
// Your html here.
$viewHelpers->table($board->getComments());
$viewHelpers->feedback($feedback);
$viewHelpers->form("", time());
```

Comment: Comment time is set when rendering the form, which probably isn't what you want. To change to the time the comment was submitted, just place `$ts = time();` within the form processing block, ignoring the posted value.